# Copying JPanel contents to another JPanel without removing contents of original JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am new to Java swing coding. I am trying to copy JPanel contents to a new JPanel which uses contents of original JPanel to show. Also, the original JPanel contents are changing as records are changing. I tried the following code but it's totally useless.

```
public void addPanel(JPanel jp)
{
    JPanel jp1=new JPanel();
    int count=jp.getComponentCount()-1;
    for(;i>=0;i--)
    {
         jp1.addComponent(jp.getComponent(i);
    }
    //after this I am setting bounds of jp1.
this.add(jp1);
}
```

This doesn't work if I want to make multiple JPanels as original JPanel changes. It overwrites the contents of new 'jp' over 'jp1' if used multiple times, say if used in a for loop.
I do not want to remove components of original JPanel. How can I do that?

Comment: *"I am trying to copy JPanel contents to a new JPanel which uses contents of original JPanel to show."*  ..Why?  Note that a component can only be added to one parent (and be seen).  That's why it is not working.

Comment: And what exactly would the `getParent()` method of those components return? Or `getRootPane()`? And which of the parents will set the width and the height of the component (which are, of course, stored in it)? JComponents were never meant to be shared, if you want copying - make copies, don't share.

Comment: Don't duplicate the _view_ component, e.g. `JComponent`; update the component's _model_, e.g. `label.setText()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving instances of Component is possible but coping them requires you to do it manually.

You can do this as a program by creating new instances of the origin class and then calling the setters with the values of the getters... But frankly, thats an error prone way and you'll need reflection for it which you shouldn't use unless really necessary.

What you can do is to override the standard Java Classes you use (e.G. JLabel) and in your overridden class you implement `Cloneable` where you set the parameters you need (text, bounds, whatever) then call your function like this:

```
public void addPanel(JPanel jp)
{
    JPanel jp1=new JPanel();
    int i=jp.getComponentCount()-1;
    for(;i>=0;i--)
    {
         jp1.addComponent(
              ((Component) // this casts the clone back to component. This is maybe superfluous.
               ((Cloneable)jp.getComponent(i) // You have to ensure that all components that are returned are in fact instances of Cloneable.
               ).clone()
              ));
    }
    //after this I am setting bounds of jp1.
    this.add(jp1);
}
```

If you go down that road, be sure to read the Documentation of [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

Comment: Thank u Angelo for the solution! As it is suggested to have only one parent for any swing component, I adopted a different approach to solve the issue. I tried a sample application using your code and it worked!

Comment: @mapp_301092 Thank you. If this answer helped you, please check the "accept" hook on the left or even better, provide your own answer with the specifics on how you solved the problem in the end so it serves future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is method for solving the following problem without coding just using design views of JPanels/JFrames.

You can go to **Navigator** in *design view* select all JPanel components and copy them by typing **ctrl+a** and **ctrl+c**.
Then create another one JPanel and in *design view*, just paste them with **ctrl+v**.

Result: You get all components same size, dimensions and positions with same properties and values. After you do this, you can easily change whatever you want by using properties of GUI forms.